# Setting distance between lines with a defined length (pt,cm,...)

Tags: line-spacing

I am currently writing a report for my Master's degree, and I have been instructed that the distance between successive lines should be at least 4mm or 13pt.

In a text-editing package like Microsoft Word, this is typically achieved by directly setting a line spacing parameter to 13pt.

However, LaTeX has different rules and seems to have a more complicated line spacing. At the moment my document set up looks like the following:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}
\usepackage{fullpage}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}    
\usepackage[parfill]{parskip}

% Other packages I don't think are relevant

\begin{document}
% Content
\end{document}
```

I am aware of the `setspace` package, but it doesn't seem to be intuitive to me how I can directly set a distance between lines?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `\usepackage{leading}` and set distance between two lines with `\leading{13pt}` to `13pt`.  The com­mand re­places the rather more dif­fi­cult LaTeX com­mand `\line­spread{<ra­tio>}`, where the lead­ing is spec­i­fied by ref­er­ence to the font size. See: [leading package](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/leading)

MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}
\usepackage{fullpage}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}    
\usepackage[parfill]{parskip}

    \usepackage{leading}
    \leading{13pt}
    \usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}
\blinddocument
\end{document}
```