# Set Linespace in Koma class to 18pt

Tags: koma-script, line-spacing

my school asks me to set my linespace to 18pt while using 12pt font size. Is there a way to spesficlly set 18pt in the `scrreprt` class or is `onehalf` the equivalent when using 12pt font size?

Comment: Have a look to [Setting distance between lines](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/358609/124842). `\usepackage{leading}` could help.  And fontsize just `[fontsize=12pt]`.

Answer (score 1):

For comparison:

```
\documentclass[fontsize=12pt]{scrreprt}

\usepackage{setspace}

\begin{document}
{\onehalfspacing
\the\baselineskip}

{\setstretch{1.24138}
\the\baselineskip}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: me, beging slow in my thinking, understands, that I am fine with onehalfspacing. Am I correct?

Comment: @Redfox87678 I don't think any normal human being can spot the difference. Both solutions do more or less the same (`\setstretch` is as `\onehalfspacing` part of the `setspace`-package).